# compile for synology issue

Tags: compilation, synology

When trying to compile tomcat 9 to run on my synology nas it gives the
following error

```
[james@centos-compile toolkit]$ sudo ./pkgscripts/PkgCreate.py -I --no-sign ${project}
[sudo] password for james: 
usage: PkgCreate.py [-h] [-p PLATFORMS] [-e ENV_SECTION] [-v ENV_VERSION]
                    [-x DEP_LEVEL] [-b BRANCH] [-s SUFFIX] [-c] [-U] [-L] [-B]
                    [-I] [-i] [-S] [--build-opt BUILD_OPT]
                    [--install-opt INSTALL_OPT] [--print-log]
                    [--min-sdk SDK_VER]
                    package
PkgCreate.py: error: the following arguments are required: package
[james@centos-compile toolkit]$
```

I'm a bit confused about this since the ${project} does have package in it

```
[james@centos-compile source]$ ls 
conf  INFO  package.tgz  scripts  WIZARD_UIFILES
```

If someone could give some advice with this I would appreciate it

Best Regards

James

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have a similiar problem. I have embedded Tomcat9 to my springboot java-app but it wont start on my Synology NAS due to a Tomcat9 related crash.
I am currently looking for answers, but I'm afraid it just wont work with tomcat9 on Synology NAS.

If you enter SynologyNAS webinterface you can find Tomcat6 and Tomcat7 as available add-ons for the NAS. I'm starting to think that there are good reasons why you can't install Tomcat8 or Tomcat9. Probably because Synology NAS doesn't support it, hence it will not work as an embedded servlet either.

Note that I am not sure at all, but this is my theory. Seems very weird to me that my brand new NAS don't support any recent versions.

If you find a way, please share! Would be so nice to be able to use my NAS for free instead of paying a host to be online 24/7. This was a big reason why I invested in a new NAS, but I'm new to coding and seem to have made a fatal mistake in chosing Synology or perhaps NAS instead of building an actual server.

I have asked about this in the Synology Community with no answers. See link:
https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/125742

EDIT: I'm still not sure we have the same problem considering I don't compile or deploy my app the same way you do, but I finally managed to run my webapp from my NAS! I replaced Tomcat9 with Jetty instead. Assuming that you use springboot like me you replace it like this in your pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```